# dynamically do changes in UI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF and C#. I need to create a Label and a Button which is in a Template.xaml. But the number of Label and Button creation is user specific which is another design.xaml. i.e if the user gives value 5, then five Label and Button needs to be created using the Template.xaml file.

I tried with something like below in design.xaml,

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserDesign"

<local:Template HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
<local:Template HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
<local:Template HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

But this seems to be a fixed one. I need to do this dynamically based on user input.

Comment: You can create a ItemsControl or Listbox to generate the list of button and textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Without a more complete code example, it's hard to know exactly what your scenario is. But if what you're dealing with is a collection of objects, where each object corresponds to a single instance of some `Template` object (which presumably contains your `Label` and `Button` object), then you probably want to use WPF's data-templating features.

There is a reasonably good tutorial here: [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx)

The basic idea is to declare a `DataTemplate` object which is used for the `ItemTemplate` property of `ItemsControl` or a sub-class (e.g. `ListBox`). The `DataTemplate` will be declared to apply to a specific data type (e.g. the object type in your collection), and you will use bindings between the UI elements in the template and the data type to customize those elements for each data object.

Depending on what your `Template` itself is declared as, that might wind up being appropriate for use in a `DataTemplate` declaration. Or it might not…it's impossible to say without seeing [an actual good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).